# Why Gaussian latent variable (noise) for GAN?

Tags: deep-learning, gan, gaussian

When I was reading about GAN, the thing I don't understand is why people often choose the input to a GAN (z) to be samples from a Gaussian? - and then are there also potential problems associated with this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why people often choose the input to a GAN (z)
>   to be samples from a Gaussian?

Generally, for two reasons: (1) mathematical simplicity, (2) working well enough in practice. However, as we explain, under additional assumptions the choice of Gaussian could be more justified.

**Compare to uniform distribution**. Gaussian distribution is not as simple as [uniform distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_(continuous)) but it is not that far off either. It adds "concentration around the mean" assumption to uniformity, which gives us the benefits of [parameter regularization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regularization_(mathematics)) in practical problems.

**The least known**. Use of Gaussian is best justified for continuous quantities that are *the least known* to us, e.g. noise $\epsilon$ or latent factor $z$. "The least known" could be formalized as "[distribution that maximizes entropy for a given variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_entropy_probability_distribution#Specified_variance:_the_normal_distribution)". The answer to this optimization is $N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ for arbitrary mean $\mu$. Therefore, in this sense, if we assume that a quantity is the least known to us, the **best** choice is Gaussian. Of course, if we acquire more knowledge about that quantity, we can do better than "the least known" assumption, as will be illustrated in the following examples.

**Central limit theorem**. Another commonly used justification is that since many observations are the result (average) of large number of [almost] independent processes, therefore [CLT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem) justifies the choice of Gaussian. This is not a good justification because there are also many real-world phenomena that do not obey Normality (e.g. [Power-law distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_law#Examples)), and since the variable is *the least known* to us, we cannot decide which of these real-world analogies are more preferable.

This would be the answer to "why we assume a Gaussian noise in [probabilistic regression](http://bjlkeng.github.io/posts/a-probabilistic-view-of-regression/) or [Kalman filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_filter)?" too.

> Are there also potential problems associated with this?

Yes. When we assume Gaussian, we are simplifying. If our simplification is unjustified, our model will under-perform. At this point, we should search for an alternative assumption. In practice, when we make a new assumption about the least known quantity (based on acquired knowledge or speculation), we could extract that assumption and introduce a **new** Gaussian one, instead of changing the Gaussian assumption. Here are two examples:

1. **Example in regression (noise)**. Suppose we have no knowledge about observation $A$ (the least known), thus we assume $A \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$. After fitting the model, we may observe that the estimated variance $\hat{\sigma}^2$ is high. After some investigation, we  may assume that $A$ is a linear function of measurement $B$, thus we extract this assumption as $A = \color{blue}{b_1B +c} + \epsilon_1$, where $\epsilon_1 \sim N(0, \sigma_1^2)$ is the new "the least known". Later, we may find out that our linearity assumption is also weak since, after fitting the model, the observed $\hat{\epsilon}_1 = A - \hat{b}_1B -\hat{c}$ also has a high  $\hat{\sigma}_1^2$. Then, we may extract a new assumption as $A = b_1B + \color{blue}{b_2B^2} + c + \epsilon_2$, where $\epsilon_2 \sim N(0, \sigma_2^2)$ is the new "the least known", and so on.
2. **Example in GAN (latent factor)**. Upon seeing unrealistic outputs from GAN (knowledge) we may add $\color{blue}{\text{more layers}}$ between $z$ and the output (extract assumption), in the hope that the new network (or function) with the new $z_2 \sim N(0, \sigma_2^2)$ would lead to more realistic outputs, and so on.